# How best to escalate a flight delay complaint?

Tags: delays, easyjet

I made two claims for an Easyjet delayed flight: one for compensation and one for expenses.
Both were replied immediately.

The expenses were accepted, the compensation not.

The replies came from ¨donotreply¨emails and the one rejecting the claim says I am not entitled and then cites WHO can make a claim under the Regulation.

It then copies the following (which of course I had read before claiming):

¨The lead booker is able to make a claim for themselves, they are also entitled to claim for all other passengers on their booking.¨

But I AM the lead booker, therefore their answer makes no sense.
How would you advise me to escalate?

Fill in a new form??
Go through Resolver?? (as advised on MoneySavingExpert, although many people say it is pointless)
Go through an ADR body, as the CAA recommends?

The last two options are going to be very protracted so I would like to choose the right one.
As for the first option, I do not know if you are supposed to fill in the same form twice.

I am aware EJ will do everything in their power to discourage me, but we paid a lot of money for the whole family and the delay was more than 20 hours.
We lost a full day.

I do not think there were extraordinary circumstances since they would have been mentioned in the ridiculous reply I received.
Certainly none that were obvious.

Many thanks

Comment: The rules and enforcement authority can vary with the itinerary. Thus: from what airport did the flight depart? At which airport did the flight arrive?

Comment: Arrived at Gatwick.
The delayed flight ticks all the boxes (as per the CAA and the MSE sites)

Comment: I see you are in America. In Europe we have EC261 claims, same rules, no different enforcement authorities.

Comment: Yes, folks here are familiar with EC261. EasyJet is a UK airline and Gatwick a UK airport, so you will only be eligible for EC261 claims if your flight departed from an EU airport. If the flight departed from somewhere outside the EU, you'll be limited to claims under the UK's adoption (as of Brexit) of EC261-like rules. The newly-enacted UK rules are usually referred-to as "UK261. " Because the rules were enacted by different political entities (the EU and the UK),  the UK rules' enforcement in the UK is wholly distinct from EC261 enforcement in the EU. They are different authorities.